# Steps to recover from the stuck-in-power-armor bug?

Tags: fallout-76

Some players in Fallout 76 are becoming stuck in their power armor and unable to exit.

After using power armor over a hundred times in the game, I have now been hit by this glitch.

My character becomes distorted and I cannot exit the armor normally and the armor doesn't function.  One of the fixes I've seen is to die and then close the game completely instead of respawning.  For me, this does get me out of the armor, but the bug reoccurs every time I try to use any power armor.  Is there a way to cure this glitch?

Answer (score 2):

Take off all armor from the chassis, deplete power core, don't take it out, it has to deplete or it doesn't work.. Sneaking and sprinting works best.

Then die and quit the game, reload and should be fixed.